# unique id , id name for generated rectangles in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The following code generates 11 squares using D3:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.3.0/d3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var width = 1000,
    height = 250,
    margin = 4,
    nRect = 11,
    rectWidth = (width - (nRect - 1) * margin) / nRect,

    svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

  var data = d3.range(nRect),
    posScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain(d3.extent(data))
      .range([0, width - rectWidth]);

  svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', posScale)
    .attr('width', rectWidth)
    .attr('height', height);


</script>
```

My plan is to use those squares later as links, is there anyway I can put a unique ID or name on every square generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is using the rectangles' indices:

```
.attr("id", function(d,i){ return "rect" + i})
```

Have in mind that IDs cannot start by number. That's why I'm concatenating the string `rect` with each rectangle's index.

Here is a demo:

```js
var width = 1000,
  height = 250,
  margin = 4,
  nRect = 11,
  rectWidth = (width - (nRect - 1) * margin) / nRect,

  svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);

var data = d3.range(nRect),
  posScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data))
  .range([0, width - rectWidth]);

svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr("id", function(d,i){ return "rect" + i})
  .attr('x', posScale)
  .attr('width', rectWidth)
  .attr('height', height);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: nice , this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks