# Add small rectangles inside BIG rectangles with unique Ids and links in D3? after an specific ID

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In my previous question I asked how could I generate unique IDs for generated rectangles [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43358364/unique-id-id-name-for-generated-rectangles-in-d3)

Now, I've been trying to draw small rectangles inside those rectangles. However, `id="rectup0"` can only have 4 small rect with unique `xlink:href` attribute
the rest of them can have 2 rectangles inside.

```
<body>
<div id="chart">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.3.0/d3.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var width = 1000,
          height = 250,
          margin = 7,
          nRect = 11,
          rectWidth = (width - (nRect - 1) * margin) / nRect,

          svgContainer = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
              .attr('width', width)
              .attr('height', height),

          svgWalkway = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
            .attr('width', '1000')
            .attr('height', '150'),

          svgContainer2 = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height);


// Rectangles scaling

      var firstRow = d3.range(nRect),
          posxScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain(d3.extent(firstRow))
            .range([0, width - rectWidth]);

      var middleRow = d3.range(1),
          posxScale3 = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain(d3.extent(middleRow))
            .range([0, width - rectWidth]);

      var secondRow = d3.range(nRect),
          posxScale2 = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain(d3.extent(secondRow))
            .range([0, width - rectWidth]);

      //Drawing the actual objects HTML rects    
      svgContainer.selectAll('rect.up')
        .data(firstRow)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr("id", function(d,i){ return "rectup" + i })
        .attr('x', posxScale)
        .attr('width', rectWidth)
        .attr('height', height)
        .attr('class','up');

      svgWalkway.selectAll('rect.middle')
        .data(middleRow)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x', posxScale3)
        .attr('width','1000')
        .attr('height','150')
        .attr('class', 'middle');


      svgContainer2.selectAll('rect.down')
        .data(secondRow)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('id', function (d,i) { return "rectdown" + i })
        .attr('x', posxScale2)
        .attr('width', rectWidth)
        .attr('height', height)
        .attr('class', 'down')
        .attr('y', 0);
    </script>
</div>
</body>
```

I've tried drawing similar rectangles like the previous ones (using `.append()`) but so far that just put them next to `svgContainer`. I've been reading some posts regarding using grouping, tried it but didn't work. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

so basically, the whole question can be resumed as adding a `rect` tag right *after* `rect id="rectup0"` so I can have

```
<rect id="rectup0"></rect>
<rect id="redrect" x="0" width="20" height="40"></rect>
```

I know `JQuery` lets you add class attributes to other classes, but not sure about D3 , this will be something like adding a new `rect` tag programmatically. is that even possible?

**UPDATE 2**

I guess it is possible with `d3.insert`, with the following:

```
d3.select('#rectup0').insert('rect')
  .attr('id', 'redrect')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('width', '20')
  .attr('height', '40');
```

however it gets it in the middle of the beginning and closing `rect` tag like this

```
<rect id="rectup0">
    <rect id="redrect" x="0" width="20" height="40"></rect>
</rect>
```

Needless to say this doesn't work because of the closing `rect` tag

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing right now. Do you want: 1. append an element right after another element? (which makes no visual difference, btw) 2. Add classes without erasing the previous class? 3. draw a rectangle inside another rectangle?

Comment: draw a rectangle inside another rectangle...the rest of them were my attempts to solve the initial question

Comment: I think the whole problem relies on the fact that the inisde rectangles have to be drawn after a determined id in this case #rectup0

Comment: rectangles can't be nested in markup. To draw a rectangle inside another rectangle you simply draw them as siblings the second will draw on top of the first, if its co-ordinates are within the bounds of the first rectangle it will appear to be "inside"

Comment: As Robert Longson just said, the only thing that matters to draw a rectangle inside another one are the coordinates. The rectangles can be even in totally separated groups. That's why your question was not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the trick with `each` wrapper for selected data. It accepts 3 arguments: current data `d`, current index `i`, and whole array of data `arr`. So if you need some kind of checks, should you append the small `rect`, or not, you can create a helper function:

```
var testIndex = function(d, i, arr) {
    return
      // test index
      i == 5 ||
      // test current data
      d == 10 ||
      // test other array members, which would be an EnterNode here
      (i > 0 && arr[i - 1]['__data__'] == 7);  
}

// do checks in one line:
var testIndex = function (d, i, arr) { return i == 4 || i == 10 || i == 7; }

var data = svgContainer.selectAll('rect.up')
  .data(firstRow);

data
  .enter()
  .each(function (d, i, arr) {
    // select DOM element to add the rects
    t = d3.select(this);

    t
      .append('rect')
      // note that here we use empty the parameters list
      .attr('id', 'rectup' + i)
      .attr('x', posxScale)
      .attr('width', rectWidth)
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('class','up');

    if (!testIndex(d, i, arr)) {
      return;
    }

    t
      .append('rect')
      .attr('id', 'redrect' + i)
      // note that we need to define x-coord similar to first rect
      .attr('x', posxScale)
      .attr('class', 'redrect');
});

// remove your data before redraw
data
  .exit()
  .remove();
```

Output:

```
<svg width="1000" height="250">
  <rect id="rectup0" x="0" width="84.54545454545455" height="250" class="up"></rect>
  <rect id="rectup1" x="91.54545454545456" width="84.54545454545455" height="250" class="up"></rect>
  <rect id="rectup2" x="183.09090909090912" width="84.54545454545455" height="250" class="up"></rect>
  <rect id="rectup3" x="274.6363636363636" width="84.54545454545455" height="250" class="up"></rect>
  <rect id="rectup4" x="366.18181818181824" width="84.54545454545455" height="250" class="up"></rect>
  <rect id="rectup5" x="457.72727272727275" width="84.54545454545455" height="250" class="up"></rect>
  <rect id="redrect5" x="457.72727272727275" class="redrect"></rect>
  <rect id="rectup6" x="549.2727272727273" width="84.54545454545455" height="250" class="up"></rect>
  <rect id="rectup7" x="640.8181818181818" width="84.54545454545455" height="250" class="up"></rect>
  <rect id="redrect7" x="732.3636363636365" class="redrect"></rect>
  <rect id="rectup8" x="732.3636363636365" width="84.54545454545455" height="250" class="up"></rect>
  <rect id="rectup9" x="823.909090909091" width="84.54545454545455" height="250" class="up"></rect>
  <rect id="rectup10" x="915.4545454545455" width="84.54545454545455" height="250" class="up"></rect>
  <rect id="redrect10" x="915.4545454545455" class="redrect"></rect>
</svg>
```

The downside of such method is that you can't provide a `attr` parameter as JSON:

```
// wouldn't work
.attr({
  id: 'redrect',
  x: posxScale,
  width: '20',
  height: '40'
});
```